# how to get a year history of data in dax

Tags: excel, mdx, pivot-table, dax, tabular

```
IIF(SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[Qty]
 ) = 0, 0,
SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[Num]
 ) /

SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(11) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[Qty]
 ) )
```

This is formula from multi dimensional model i am trying to convert this MDX formula to DAX formula to use in Tubular model.

```
12 Month Avg  :=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [QTY] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Calendar[Month] ),
            Calendar[Month] - 11
                = ( Calendar[Month] - 11 )
        )
    )
        = 0,
    BLANK (),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [Num] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Calendar[Month] ),
            Calendar[Month] - 11
                = ( Calendar[Month] - 11 )
        )
    )
        / CALCULATE (
            SUM ( [QTY] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( Calendar[Month] ),
                Calendar[Month] - 11
                    = ( Calendar[Month] - 11 )
            )
        )
)
```

So i made this DAX formula to convert MDX formula at the top. However it seem not working properly when i select month in pivot table. Those two formula don't match when i filtered by month. How can i resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create three base measures:

```
TotalNum := SUM([Num])

TotalQty := SUM([Qty])

Avg := DIVIDE ( [TotalNum], [TotalQty], 0 )
```

2) Create a calculated measure to calculate the average over the prior year including the current selected month:

```
AvgLastYear:= CALCULATE ( 
   [Avg] , 
   DATESINPERIOD ( 
       Calendar[Date] , 
       MAX(Calendar[Date]),
       -1, year
   ) 
)
```

Explanation:

First, you don't need that divide by zero rigmarole, both MDX and DAX have a DIVIDE() function which handles that implicitly.

Second, with DAX, the idea is to build a base measure and then use CALCULATE() to shift the context of that measure as needed - in this case the time period.

Here we're looking at the current selected month (represented as `MAX(Calendar[Date])`, though you could use any aggregation function) and then using `DATESINPERIOD()` to choose a set of dates in our `Calendar` table which represent the time period T-1 year to the current month.

Comment: Thank you for your help & explanation. But What if i have date keys like 201301?

Comment: (upped) nice post as I'd not realised that the `divide` function even existed in `mdx`! Here is a good reference to it: http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/07/26/new-mdx-divide-function/

Comment: @HAIZD Just create a calculated column that turns your date keys into a field with a Date type.

Comment: Thanks for replying comment. So I changed my date format to YYYY-MM-DD and it allowed me to make measurement.However when I run the measurement through excel, it gives me "An Invalid numeric representation of a data value was encountered." What should i check if I got that error?

Comment: That error means one of the dates you're selecting in your DATESINPERIOD or DATESBETWEEN function doesn't exist in the Calendar table, you have to choose existing dates in your date column.